# Search an Array for Entry with a Class

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have created an array with jQuery and I would like to be able to check the array and find an entry that has the class `.active` and return the index of the entry.

I have attempted this `var index = $.inArray($(.active), array);` and have had no luck.

Is this even possible, if so, how?

(See picture for what the array looks like.)

https://jsfiddle.net/e2ubdrbq/

[image: My array]

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: If your array is in the variable `arr` and contains JQuery DOM nodes, as suggested by screenshot, you could filter it like so `var entry = arr.filter(it => it[0].hasClass('active'))[0]`

Comment: Chill out, Liam. Have added Fiddle to question, testing out suggestions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated the JSFiddle to include the solution I used.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2ubdrbq/1/

This is the markup we create the array from:

```
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="search"></div>
<div class="array"></div>
<div class="jquery"></div>
<div class="active"></div>
```

This is the loop to create the array:

```
var array = [];

$('div').each(function() {
    array.push($(this));
})
```

This is the function that will return the index of the element that has the class `.active`:

```
function get_index(arr) {
    var i;
    $(arr).filter(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            i = index;
        }
    });
    return i;
}

var index = get_index(array);

console.log(index);
```

Thanks to user [AJDEV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3584674/ajdev) for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To find element:

```
array.filter('.active')
```

To find index and element:

```
array.map((index, el) => {
    return $(el).hasClass('active') ? {index, el} : null
})
```